# Xcode: Match-O Linker (Id) Error when building HID Explorer

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I want to build the HID Explorer example in Xcode 4, but when I try to build, I get these errors (no matter if its 32 or 64):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_DisposeMenu", referenced from:
      _Handle_WindowEvents in main.o
  "_GetControl32BitMaximum", referenced from:
      _Handle_EventControlDraw in main.o
  "_GetControl32BitMinimum", referenced from:
      _Handle_EventControlDraw in main.o
  "_GetControl32BitValue", referenced from:
      _Handle_EventControlDraw in main.o
  "_InvalWindowRect", referenced from:
      _SetElementTitle in main.o
  "_SetControl32BitMaximum", referenced from:
      _Update_WindowElementInfo in main.o
  "_SetControl32BitMinimum", referenced from:
      _Update_WindowElementInfo in main.o
  "_SetControl32BitValue", referenced from:
      _DisplayCurrentDeviceElementValue in main.o
  "_SetControlMaximum", referenced from:
      _Build_DeviceMenu in main.o
      _Build_ElementMenu in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I assume, there is a framework missing. Can anyone tell, which one?

Frameworks already included are:
CoreFoundation.framework, IOKit.framework, Carbon.framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to re-write the code itself the only valid architectures are (ppc, and i386). I reproduced the exact errors when I tried to build the project with **x86_64** included. When I removed that architecture the project built and ran just fine.

Valid architectures: **ppc i386** or just **i386**

[image: valid arches]

Answer (score 0):

HID Explorer is a Legacy Carbon sample that used IOKit to talk to HID devices. You should consider using the HID Manager introduced in 10.5 instead. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html.

Here's some minimal code to iterate all connected HID devices using the HID Manager:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    IOHIDManagerRef tIOHIDManagerRef = NULL;
    CFSetRef deviceCFSetRef = NULL;
    IOHIDDeviceRef *tIOHIDDeviceRefs = nil;

    do {    // psudo try/throw block
        tIOHIDManagerRef = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
        if (!tIOHIDManagerRef) break;

        IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(tIOHIDManagerRef, NULL);

        IOReturn tIOReturn = IOHIDManagerOpen(tIOHIDManagerRef, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
        if (noErr != tIOReturn) break;

        deviceCFSetRef = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(tIOHIDManagerRef);
        if (!deviceCFSetRef) break;

        CFIndex deviceIndex, deviceCount = CFSetGetCount(deviceCFSetRef);

        tIOHIDDeviceRefs = malloc(sizeof(IOHIDDeviceRef) * deviceCount);
        if (!tIOHIDDeviceRefs) break;

        CFSetGetValues(deviceCFSetRef, (const void **)tIOHIDDeviceRefs);
        CFRelease(deviceCFSetRef);
        deviceCFSetRef = NULL;
        for (deviceIndex = 0; deviceIndex < deviceCount; deviceIndex++) {
            if (!tIOHIDDeviceRefs[deviceIndex]) continue;

            // dump the HID device info 
            // HIDDumpDeviceInfo(tIOHIDDeviceRefs[deviceIndex]);
        }
    } while (false);

    if (tIOHIDDeviceRefs) {
        free(tIOHIDDeviceRefs);
    }
    if (deviceCFSetRef) {
        CFRelease(deviceCFSetRef);
        deviceCFSetRef = NULL;
    }
    if (tIOHIDManagerRef) {
        CFRelease(tIOHIDManagerRef);
    }

    return (0);
} // main
```

Comment: You are right, I changed my code already. But the HID Explorer is a handy tool to see connected devices.

Comment: The HID Calibrator sample will create a window for each connected HID device and then enumerate each input or feature element of each device. Email me at <geowar1 @ mac . com> (san spaces) for a Cocoa version.